# Capturing development/aid project perfromance in IATI format

Tags: standards, iati, ict4d, aid

IATI Standard has "result" element, which includes "baseline" and "indicator" elements to represent project performance. http://iatistandard.org/activities-standard/result/

Is there an example how it should be structured?

I have projects' performance data in following format:

```
+--------------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+----------+----------+---------+
|   country    |            project            |                        activity                        |                                                                            kpi                                                                            | baseline |  target  |  actual  | percent |
+--------------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+----------+----------+---------+
| Burkina Faso | Rural Land Governance Project | All Activities                                         | Trend in incidence of conflict over land rights reported in the 17 pilot communes (Annual rate of change in the occurrence of conflicts over land rights) | 6.5      | 5.7      | Pending  | Pending |
| Burkina Faso | Rural Land Governance Project | Legal and Procedural Change and Communication Activity | Legal and regulatory reforms adopted                                                                                                                      | 0        | 42       | 51       | 121%    |
| Burkina Faso | Rural Land Governance Project | Legal and Procedural Change and Communication Activity | Stakeholders reached by public outreach efforts                                                                                                           | 0        | "14,100" | "43,632" | 309%    |
+--------------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+----------+----------+---------+
```

Those are for one single fiscal quarter (let's say FY2012 Q4).

What will be XML structure representing this data?

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell what you're asking here. You may want to restate the title as a question and clarify a bit in the text.

Answer (score 3):

You attach a result to a specific activity, so in this case the **Legal and Procedural Change and Communication Activity**. The  should be nested within that activity. You can have many results, which are just siblings.

A single result should look something like this:

```
<result type="2">
  <title>Stakeholders reached by public outreach efforts</title>
  <indicator measure="1">
     <period>
       <period-start iso-date = "YYYY-MM-DD" />
       <period-end iso-date = "YYYY-MM-DD" />
       <target value = "14100" />
       <actual value = "43632" />
     </period>
     <baseline year = "YYYY" value="0" />
  </indicator>
</result>
```

A few points:

- values should not include commas
- the start and end dates could just be taken from the start and end dates of the activity
- the baseline year can just be the start year of the activity.
- check that you are happy with these assumptions:

  - `result type="2"` refers to the [Result Type codelist](http://iatistandard.org/codelists/result_type/) - states that it is an **outcome**
  - `indicator measure="1"` refers to the [Indicator Measure codelist](http://iatistandard.org/codelists/indicator_measure/) - states that it is a **unit**
- for the **All Activities** indicator, I would attach that to the parent project. Where you have "pending" for the `actual` element, you should leave the element out for now.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the latest IATI annual report ( http://www.aidtransparency.net/news/media-release-22-april-2013-first-iati-annual-report-published )
on page 18pp - who's publishing what.

There are currently 6 organisations listed that are publishing results - one of those that provides some result entries similar to your requirements is the GFATM.

To see the formatting, preview one of the activity files on http://www.iatiregistry.org/dataset?q=&publishertype=&secondary_publisher=&groups=theglobalfund